# ZXing QRCodeReader Java build error

Tags: java, maven, zxing

I am learning how this package works but having issues just getting it to build.

I grabbed ZXing reader from here ==> https://github.com/zxing/zxing

I also went to this site for a guide ==> https://www.callicoder.com/qr-code-reader-scanner-in-java-using-zxing/

So i opened up the pom.xml and i get all the modules .github, .idea, android, android-core, android-integration, core, docs, javase, src, zxing.appspot.com and zxingorg.

I then go to zxingorg/src/main/java/com.google.zxing.web and same for core module pasted qrcodereader in there and tried running it and i get this error.

"Error:Android Pre Dex: [android] Android SDK is not specified"

Now i do get an error saying android sdk needed api level 22 but....im not even developing for android. I was just planning on working just for pc/raspberry pi applications. Not android.

I was under the presumption that the ZXing library was usable for desktop applications and the like??

I am using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/callicoder/qr-code-generator-and-reader

this was the answer. i was importing all of it and it was using the wrong version and it was android modules attached.

i imported the above and worked like a charm. Please close this.